# AWStats time zone used in statistics

Tags: godaddy, awstats

Simple question, the **Hours** statistics shown in GoDaddy Awstats which time zone use?

Is the server timezone?

The server logs show time with this timezone `07/Oct/2015:05:16:32 -0700`, so it's `UTC-07:00`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/docs/awstats_faq.html#DIFFERENCE_HOURS):

> AWStats use only time reported in logs by your server and all time are related to server hour.

Comment: Which ought to be UTC, but I didn't check for GoDaddy.